# Angular.js click through to item details page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I'm quire new to Angular so I apologise if this has already been answered but I just couldn't figure it out when I see other uses for it.

I am using a REST API to simply fetch some news articles from an external URL and print them out nicely on a news listing page.

### **[Link for results](http://test.shabazejaz.co.uk/)**

(You can see the output of the JSON in the console)

The JSON that is returned looks like this (just showing one set):

```
   [
     {
        "author":"Napier Lopez",
        "title":"Report: First real Samsung Galaxy S8 photo and release date leaked",
        "description":"Ever-reliable leaker Evan Blass of Venture Beat has just given us our best look at Samsung’s Galaxy S8 yet. The report confirms several of the details we’ve already learned about the device, as well as providing an announcement and release date. Blass confirms that the devices are foregoing the front fingerprint scanner for one place on …",
        "url":"https://thenextweb.com/mobile/2017/01/26/report-first-real-samsung-galaxy-s8-photo-release-date-leaked/",
        "urlToImage":"https://cdn3.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2017/01/Samsung-Galaxy-S8-Blur-not-real.jpg",
        "publishedAt":"2017-01-26T22:13:13Z"
     } ...
  ]
```

Here is my how I've printed out each news article:

app.js:

```
/* Newsfeed API Call */
var app = angular.module('newsFeed', [])
    .controller('Newsfeed', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-next-web&sortBy=latest&apiKey=6ddf8d3cc8a54cc0abf89ad7d685da54').
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.news = response.data;
        });
    });
```

news-listing.html:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="Newsfeed">
  <br/>
  <form>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Newsfeed</h2>
      <br/>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchText" name="search-news" id="search-news" placeholder="Search for news">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="custom-select" ng-model="selectedAuthor" ng-options="n.author for n in news.articles | unique: 'author'">
          <option ng-click="selectedAuthor = undefined" value="">Filter by Author</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>


  <div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;" ng-repeat="n in news.articles | filter:searchText | filter:selectedAuthor">
      <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="{{n.urlToImage}}" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">{{n.title | cut:true:50:' ...'}}</h4>
        <p class="card-text"> {{n.author}} <small>on {{ formatDate(n.publishedAt) |  date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</small> </p>
        <p class="card-text"> {{n.description | cut:true:100:' ...'}}</p>

        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" role="button"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is that for each news article in the `news-listing` I can click on it to see more details, so I would have an articles-details page that would take some sort of unique identifier and use that to pull out all of the data.

How can I achieve this baring in mind that the response in the JSON for the articles does not contain any sort of unique ID?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `ng-repeat` there is an angular variable: `$index` which gives you the position of the element in the array (`news.articles`). You can use it in order to access to the *n* element in the array.

So, you would have a function which you would call on you **view** button like this:

```
$scope.view = function (idx){
    //get the n-esim article inside the array like something like
    var element = $scope.news[idx] //and do some stuff with element
}
```

... and in your view you would have something like

```
<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;" ng-repeat="n in news.articles | filter:searchText | filter:selectedAuthor">
      <!--...-->
      <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" ng-click="view($index)">Details</a>
      <!--...-->
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" role="button"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Right, that works fine however how would I go about creating the item details page based on the unique ID that would be passed through the URL?

Comment: Would I need some sort of routing mechanism in place?

Comment: You have two options: `1:`You can do it simply by setting the (current) selected article's data in some variable in a service, then redirect to another partial and initially load the (article) data from the service and show it in the new view....or, `2:` have a div or something  with the article data bind to the content of the selected item (but hidden) and when the user clicks the `view` function, then show that content and hide the list of articles. If I were you, I'd choose the first one, it's cleaner.